# Looking for a sci-fi movie about people who have to play a game to obtain a life-prolonging drug

Tags: story-identification, movie, dystopia, soft-sci-fi

I am looking for a sci-fi movie I remember from my youth. Given my age, I probably saw this movie in the 90es or early 2000s. I have no idea what the title was, but I remember this from the plot:

In the future, some company develops a drug that keeps you alive indefinitely, provided you take it regularly. If you stop taking the drug, you will die within a few days. 
To obtain the drug, the characters have to perform a job for the company, that involves playing some sort of computer game before an audience (some sort of e-sport?). I remember that the main protagonist was one of those players. For some reason, playing this game was an ethically questionable activity.

The plot evolves around the main characters trying to find the recipe for this drug, so it can be produced by someone other than its manufacturer.

There was also an older man who was some kind of "wise old man" character. At some point there was a big revelation that this old man was also addicted to the drug.

I also remember one scene were one of the delivery workers accidentally spilled some of the drug. The effect was that immediatelly some dead flowers on the wayside started to bloom and they had to kill the flowers with a flame-thrower.

That is about everything I can remember, I hope it triggers some memories. Of course I tried to google it, but without luck. I can't remember any names from the movie, so googling is difficult.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Good detail to start with, so thank you for that.  Not ringing any bells for me yet, although it sounds like something I should remember.  Did you see this on TV or in a theatre?  Might narrow the field.

Comment: Radhil: I have no idea where I saw this movie. I don't even know whether it is good. Its just that I seem to have remembered it over the years, so that seems to indicate I liked it back then. :)

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like [Timemaster](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114676/combined) from 1995. From an [online synopsis](http://www.chucksconnection.com/timemaster.html):

> The world has been destroyed by some sort of disaster, and the few remaining survivors are living in a "Mad Max" type of world, where they camp out in the ruins to defend themselves from raiders. [...] **a group of aliens play games that affect the past, present, and future destiny of the universe.** The aliens send "collectors" through space and time to planets where there are life forms to collect them as contestants or actually pawns for these virtual reality games, since the contestants really do not have free will over the outcomes. [...] **The aliens bet on the outcome of these games with "blue", the distilled [liquid] substance of eternal life which is extracted from the losers of the game.**

The wise old man was played by Pat Morita, and IIRC the scenes you've mentioned (him confessing to being addicted to "blue", and the drug leaking and making flowers bloom) are there. The trailer: