# A sci-fi movie from 80's or eary 90's about a drug named "blue"

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe, drug

I don't remember much, mostly the ending, but the movie has to do with an alternate place or reality from earth.

There is a drug of some sort called "blue" that is used recreational and also when people are hooked up to some sort of chair. there is a battles that are done, and I think the looser gets sorta liquefied and turned into blue?

Comment: Hi. I'm glad you want to participate, but without a lot more information this is going to be unanswerable.  For example, was this animated or live-action? Which language and what country was the movie in?

Comment: what with blue pills, alternate realities and battles this reminds me of the Matrix.

Comment: sorry for not adding more in, my apologies. it is live action, language was English, region was U.S. but there was no mention of "pills" only a drug by the name of blue. Thank you all for the help! this has been a random thought for 25 years now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this be *[Timemaster](https://www.chucksconnection.com/timemaster.html)* as per [Looking for a sci-fi movie about people who have to play a game to obtain a life-prolonging drug](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144724/looking-for-a-sci-fi-movie-about-people-who-have-to-play-a-game-to-obtain-a-life)?

> Timemaster opens in a desolate looking Yellowstone Park in the year 2007. The world has been destroyed by some sort of disaster, and the few remaining survivors are living in a “Mad Max” type of world, where they camp out in the ruins to defend themselves from raiders. Narration from a man who identifies himself as the Chairman (Michael Dorn) is heard explaining the premise of the film: on a far away planet, a group of aliens play games that affect the past, present, and future destiny of the universe. The aliens send “collectors” through space and time to planets where there are life forms to collect them as contestants or actually pawns for these virtual reality games, since the contestants really do not have free will over the outcomes. The Chairman continues by saying how Earth has been a very fertile source of life forms for their games, which have created wars, assassinations, and other forms of havoc on the planet. The aliens bet on the outcome of these games with “blue”, the distilled substance of eternal life which is extracted from the losers of the game. Isaiah (Pat Morita), their main collector on earth has been sent to gather the final contestants for thermonuclear war, which will then finish off earth. But Isaiah has become disenchanted with the games, and their intent to destroy Earth, and he plans to bring Jesse (Jesse Cameron-Glickenhaus) who he believes can successfully challenge the outcome of the games, and stop the destruction of earth. The Chairman is one step ahead, collecting Jesse’s parents as contestants in the game on his planet, while he sends Jesse and his sister Veronica (Vanessa Cameron-Glickenhaus) back in time as orphans. The Chairman says that although Isaiah may teach Jesse how to time travel, he won’t be able to stop the aliens from playing out their plan to destroy Earth. We then see his collectors invade the camp at Yellowstone, and eventually take Jesse’s parents back to their game arena, where Jesse’s mother Evelyn (Joanna Pacula) is put into a new reality game with a contestant named Mordor. The game is set in the Old West of the late 19th century and includes Jesse and his father Jonathan (Duncan Regehr) as characters in a battle of townspeople, gunfighters, and outlaws.

### The Fight for Blue

### Trailer

Found with a search for `science fiction film "drug * blue"`

Comment: YES!!! thank you so much!! it is timemaster!